# How to configure git to work witha proxy server

Tags: heroku-toolbelt

How can someone tweak aroud th heroku toolbelt i.e git and use a proxy server to connect to heroku. I am trying to connect but it keeps telling me machine actively denied it access. help

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Git proxy using the below command in the git bash. Set for both HTTP and HTTPS proxy.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@proxy.server.com:8080

//Replace username with your proxy username
//Replace password with your proxy password
//Replace proxy.server.com with the proxy domain URL.
//Replace 8080 with the proxy port no configured on the proxy server.
```

Check [How to configure Git proxy](https://itsmycode.com/get-absolute-url-using-javascript/) and [How to unset the Git Proxy](https://itsmycode.com/get-absolute-url-using-javascript/) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Set `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` system environment variables in following format if proxy sever requires authentication:

HTTP_PROXY = http://username:password@proxy.server.com:portNumber

HTTPS_PROXY = https://username:password@proxy.server.com:portNumber

Answer (score 0):

use HTTP_PROXY environemnt variable

e.g. HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:9999